# R - change data frame entries by specific string (count and replace by the value of counter, change sign)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains numbers and numbers separated by a "." and I want to change the entries dependent on the "." string. 
If the entry does not contain a "." the prefix "-" should be added. That's kind of simple using the subsetting or grep functionality. But I also want to replace the entries which contain a "." with the counter of ".".

my example data:

```
X1      X2 
1       2  
3       4
6       8
5       1.2
3.4     7
1.2.5   9
11      3.4.7
```

and I would like to have it look like this:

```
X1      X2 
-1       -2  
-3       -4
-6       -8
-5       1
2        -7
3        -9
-11      4
```

I have no clue and tried already subsetting, extracting the "." parts to count them. But I can not insert the counter. Thanks for your help.

Comment: because it's the third and 4th time a "." appears

Comment: Yes I got it. Look at my answer below

Comment: yes, thanks! :) also a nice solution, although I'm not familiar with sapply. And according to your question - how would the code look like if we want to check the numbers of the "."-entry and replace it with the row-number where the combination appeared above? So that means: 1.2. => 1, 3.4 =>2, 1.2.5 => 4, 3.4.7 => 5 ?

Comment: Here is [a link about apply family](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega). I am not sure I understand what you mean with row-number

Comment: if it is like this: Check for ".", if yes -> check where that numbers appeared already and replace the "."-entry by the number of the row where that pair of numbers appeared.

Comment: @Sotos he means that 1.2 is the combination of X1 and X2 at the row 1, and 3.4.7 is the combination of X1 and X2 at the row5.

Comment: oh, well...this really complicates things

Comment: @Miguel123 I would say look for it, and if you do not find, post your attempt in another question. You can for instance create column with X1.X2 comb and X2.X1 comb, compare with your number and keep the row when they match

Comment: can do something with `paste` maybe

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea via base R,

```
ind <- rowSums(sapply(df, function(i) cumsum(grepl('\\.', i))))
df[] <- lapply(df[], function(i) ifelse(grepl('\\.', i), ind, paste0('-', i)))

df
#   X1 X2
#1  -1 -2
#2  -3 -4
#3  -6 -8
#4  -5  1
#5   2 -7
#6   3 -9
#7 -11  4
```

**NOTE** : I converted `df` to character,

```
df[] <- lapply(df[], as.character)
```

**EDIT**

Regarding your row numbers request, then this should do it,

```
ind1 <- apply(df, 1, function(i) paste(sort(i), collapse = '.'))
df2 <- sapply(df, function(i) match(i, ind1))
df[] <- lapply(df[], function(i) ifelse(grepl('\\.', i), 0, paste0('-', i)))
df[!is.na(df2)] <- df2[!is.na(df2)]
df
#   X1 X2
#1  -1 -2
#2  -3 -4
#3  -6 -8
#4  -5  1
#5   2 -7
#6   4 -9
#7 -11  5
```

If you are planning on doing calculations with this data frame later on, then you should convert to integer, i.e.,

```
df[] <- lapply(df[], as.integer)

str(df)
#'data.frame':  7 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ X1: int  -1 -3 -6 -5 2 4 -11
# $ X2: int  -2 -4 -8 1 -7 -9 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is with data.table
The idea is to create a counter in an temporary column:

```
library(data.table)

dt<-data.table(df)
dt$X1 <- as.character(dt$X1 )
dt$X2 <- as.character(dt$X2 )
dt[!grepl(".", dt$X1, fixed=TRUE),X1:=paste("-", X1, sep="") ]
dt[!grepl(".", dt$X2, fixed=TRUE),X2:=paste("-", X2, sep="") ]
dt[grepl(".", dt$X1, fixed=TRUE)|grepl(".", dt$X2, fixed=TRUE), count_point:=as.character(sequence(.N))]
dt[grepl(".", dt$X1, fixed=TRUE),X1:=count_point]
dt[grepl(".", dt$X2, fixed=TRUE),X2:=count_point]
df <- data.frame(dt[, c("X1", "X2"), with = FALSE])
```

There should be a way to do it in less line, using `.SD`